# SWIG-PHP error: Invalid library

Tags: php, c++, swig

I'm new to SWIG and I'm trying to make a PHP5 wrapper around this library
https://sourceforge.net/projects/zinnia/

The project includes the interface file zinnia.i

Following www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html

I run

```
swig -php -c++ zinnia.i
gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c zinnia_wrap.cpp
gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib/ -lzinnia -o zinnia.so
```

Then I load it in PHP

```
extension=zinnia.so
```

But when I start apache I get this error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'zinnia.so' in Unknown on line 0

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2 Swig 1.3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you solved your problem?

I have not tried to make a PHP5 wrapper but I thought it might be worth trying to use g++ rather than gcc to generate you c++ code.

I have had linking problems when I accidentely compiled a c-library rather than a c++ library.
For example,  [SWIG ImportError: undefined symbol: _Py_RefTotal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480995/swig-importerror-undefined-symbol-py-reftotal)

Not sure if this will help, but since its quick to try I thought I mention it just in case!

Tom

Comment: For me, it was the exact opposite problem. I was using g++ to compile C++ code, when I should have been using gcc to compile C code. Once I changed everything to C and compiled using gcc, the extension was loaded correctly.